# Showing classic page instead of lightning page when i open an Opportunity from list in salesforce1/Mobile

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app

> I have a 2 salesforce account First account working according our need
>   as its showing a lightning page when i open a Opportunity from list
>   e.g

[image]

> And when i choose a Opportunity from above list

[image]

> I got correct result in above image. But In other account  When i
>   choose a list from Opportunity It showing a classic page eg.

[image]

> There must be lightning page as above result instead of a classic page

[image: There Must be a lightning page instead of classic one]

Comment: Do you have any overrides on the View action for Opportunities? Curious if you are using all standard functionality or if there is custom code involved that may be routing the user in a different way.

Comment: I guess this is getting redirected to a VF page which has only apex:detail. Could you please have a check of View Overrides?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have override visual force component instead of standard one.
Open view and click on a override VF component.

Steps->
Setup-> Object Manager -> Opportunity
Find override vf page in Action and Custom Links
There is a checkbox and make sure it's unchecked

[image]