# Visualforce disables lightning theme

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning, page-layout

I'm trying to override View action of a Standard Object (Opportunity in this case) with a Visualforce page. My override works on both Classic and Lightning theme. However, on lightning pages, my Visualforce page changes the original page's layout.

My Visualforce Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" lightningStylesheets="true">
    <apex:detail subject="{!Opportunity.Id}" relatedList="true" title="true" rendered="true" />
</apex:page>
```

It works perfectly on the Classic theme, but here is how it looks on Lightning compared to the original page without override:

[image]

How do I achieve the functionality of creating a generic Visualforce page to load both classic pages and lightning pages? And if it's not possible, what are the alternatives to achieve it?

Comment: Why do you need VF page? Can you give more info about your requirement? it looks like http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 0):

The main reason to introduce `lightningStylesheets=true` is to style the VF page components with SLDS. For example if you use `apex` components like `apex:inputField`, `apex:detail`, etc. It will try make it look like as if you have created the page using `lightning component`.

**The main thing to understand here is it won't add additional components**.

Like in `apex:detail` component we do not have `path component`  available. It will just style all the components with SLDS on the visualforce page. No additional component gets added.

Comment: So I do I get around this to achieve the functionality of creating a generic vfp to load both classic pages and lightning pages?

Comment: I suppose you will have to create a custom lightning component to handle this. This [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/172078/showing-classic-page-instead-of-lightning-page-when-i-open-an-opportunity-from-l) will help you more in differentiating the override for classic and lightning.

Answer (score 0):

**apex:detail** was designed for the classic view originally and it doesn't have components from LEX. You will have to design a vf page which adds path component when it is accessed in the LEX.